Run Time Error 1004 - the worksheet data for the table needs to be on the same sheet as the table ; happens depending from where it's executed
I have a code that works well in one place, but not in another. Normally, it's a macro that executes when you click on a button, followed by various other things : it opens another file, does some PowerQuery stuff and then closes it again.
EDIT : to be clearer, the PowerQuery is happening on the other file. The error still appears to be linked to the main file's code, but it clearly refers to the tables on the other file.
When I try to put this code in ThisWorkBook, as Sub Workbook_Open, it then will give me the Run Time error. I tried calling this snippet of code alone, it works all the time ; just not when executed on Open. I tried putting a timer before the execution, to let it "settle".
What could cause this ?
The line where it fails appears to be this one :
*ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Liste_All_Masques", Formula:= _*

Public type_reception As String
Public Backup As String
Public Layer_critique As String
Public Masks_backup As String
Public Nom_layer_critique As String
Public Compteur As Integer
Public Statut_mask As String
Public Maskset As String
Public State_Name As String
Public Cinq_digit As String
Public Deux_digit As String

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'On efface l'ancien résultat de repell form
Sheets("Ancien repell form").Activate
Sheets("Repell form").Visible = True
Call Nettoyage_repell_form

Sheets("Repell form").Activate
Range("C2:C30").Clear

type_reception = ""
Backup = ""
Layer_critique = ""
Nom_layer_critique = ""
Compteur = 0
Statut_mask = ""
Maskset = ""
State_Name = ""

'Don't show confirmation window
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    aFile = "W:\Ateliers\PHOTO\Masks\Reports_TGV_IRETICLE\Liste_All_Masques.xlsx"
    If Len(Dir$(aFile)) > 0 Then
        Kill aFile
    End If

    'Ouverture du fichier CSV
    Workbooks.Open ("W:\Ateliers\PHOTO\Masks\Reports_TGV_IRETICLE\Liste_All_Masques.CSV")
    Set All_masque = ActiveWorkbook
    'Workbooks(“Liste_All_Masques.CSV”).Activate

        ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Liste_All_Masques", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""W:\Ateliers\PHOTO\Masks\TPP_Mask\Florent\07 - Macro Renvoi-réception\Tests CSV\Liste_All_Masques.CSV""),[Delimiter=""#(tab)"", Columns=18, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Promoted Headers"" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#""Pr" & _
        "omoted Headers"",
REDACTED DATA
" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Reordered Columns"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:="OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Liste_All_Masques;Extended Properties=""""", Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Liste_All_Masques]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Liste_All_Masques"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    
    'Renommage et suppression des Feuilles
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Name = "Rapport 1"
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    'Sheets("Liste_All_Masques").Select
    'ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    
    'Sauvegarde du fichier en format .xlsx
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
        "W:\Ateliers\PHOTO\Masks\Reports_TGV_IRETICLE\Liste_All_Masques.xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'Sauvegarde du fichier sans afficher la fenêtre de confirmation
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True

'Allow confirmation windows to appear as normal
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Msgbox "Update fait"

End Sub



The issue likely arises because certain objects and processes in Excel aren't fully initialized when the Workbook_Open event triggers. Specifically, adding a Power Query query (like ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add) right at the workbook's open can cause Excel to behave unpredictably, as it may be too early for certain dependencies or add-ins to load fully.
Here are a few adjustments to help address this:
Add a Delay After Workbook Open: If you haven’t tried this yet, introduce a delay after the workbook opens. Try this version of your code that delays before adding the query:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "RunAfterOpen"
End Sub

Private Sub RunAfterOpen()
    ' Place the entire Workbook_Open code here...
End Sub

Disable Background Refresh in Power Query Settings: Since Power Queries in the Workbook_Open can cause conflicts, set .BackgroundQuery = False (which you already have). This may reduce timing-related issues.
Use DoEvents: Before adding the query, insert DoEvents to let Excel complete any pending operations. For instance, add DoEvents just before the line that adds the query:
DoEvents
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Liste_All_Masques", Formula:= _
"let" & Chr(13) & ...


I've tried the various suggestions you've provided, but it still doesn't work. I've edited my initial message with details as to where the PowerQuery stuff is happening - on the other file opened in the background. It's where the tables are said to not work. However, it works flawlessly when executed on its own, and not on opening...
